# comparison .tex files and export pdf

Tags: comparison

I would like to compare two `.tex` files (before and after modifications) and then edit a `.pdf` with for instance, the added lines in green and those removed in red.

Is there a simple tool to do so?

Comment: What do you mean by `edit a .pdf`? You can certainly produce a PDF marked up with changes. `latexdiff` is one option.

Comment: @cfr this is a very good answer